# Operations with a static row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df with the percentage of good, regular and bad students in two classrooms in the first two rows, and with the percentage of good, regular and bad students in the whole school, like this:

```
  Classr Good Regular   Bad 
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> 
1 A        30      10    60   
2 B        40      10    50   
3 PR       80      10    10
```

I need to calculate an index for any classroom which is the result of

|PRGood-GoodA|+|PRRegular-RegularA|+|PRBad-BadA|  and for classroom B
|PRGood-GoodB|+|PRRegular-RegularB|+|PRBad-BadB|

In this example, the result should be:

```
  Classr Good Regular   Bad  INDEX
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A        30      10    60    100  
2 B        40      10    50     80
3 PR       80      10    10     NA <- This value doesn't matter
```

Any idea on how to do so?

I tried with this code but I get an error message:

```
df%>%
  mutate(across(2:4, ~.-tail(1,across(2:4)),))
```

Comment: if you only have class a and b you can sum the results of the other class and get the index that class.

Comment: The real df have thousands of classrooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate(d, INDEX = rowSums(across(c(Good, Regular, Bad), ~ abs(.x[length(.x)] - .x))))
#>   Classr Good Regular Bad INDEX
#> 1      A   30      10  60   100
#> 2      B   40      10  50    80
#> 3     PR   80      10  10     0
```

**DATA**

```
d <- structure(list(Classr = c("A", "B", "PR"), Good = c(
  30L, 40L,
  80L
), Regular = c(10L, 10L, 10L), Bad = c(60L, 50L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3"
))
```

Comment: I'm trying with the real df but still don't have the result I'm looking for. For any reason the 'INDEX' is repeating the same number for all the rows.

Comment: Hm. Hard to tell without a look at your real data. So I can only guess. Have you checked that your data is not grouped?

Comment: I eddited the question to explain better myself. With your code the `TOTAL` is recalculated using `~ sum(.x)`, right? That is not possible to do with the real df since it have percentages — which are provided directly by the source.

Comment: Yep. If it's not possible to compute the totals row from the data a different approach is needed. Will remove my answer and may have another look.

Comment: @JoséRojas. Did some small adjustments. Now the totals are taken from the last row of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is workin. Could you, please, explain me how the `~ abs(.x[length(.x)] - .x))` works? I'm not sure about it. I mean, what do you "tell" R to do with the `.x` and in general with this part of the code? Is the first time I see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.x` is a vector, `.x[length(.x)]` is the last element of the vector and with`.x[length(.x)] - .x` the vector minus the last element (or the other way around) and `abs(...)` the absolute value (Try it in the console: Use e.g. `.x <- c(1,2,3); abs(.x[length(.x)] - .x))`) Using `across` we do this calculation for each of your columns and finally take the rowwise sum via `rowSums`.